# Evaluate the integral: $\lim \limits_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1\frac{nx}{nx^3+1}$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

Evaluate the integral:
$$\lim \limits_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1\frac{nx}{nx^3+1}dx$$

I'm pretty much stuck on how to solve this one:
$$\int_0^1\frac{nx}{nx^3+1}dx$$

or even getting the improper integral.

What can i do?

Comment: Do you know about the Dominated Convergence Theorem? Your problem is a simple application of it.

Comment: The text of the OP should rather read: "evaluate the limit of this ... integral". BTW the integral can be evaluated exactly $\frac{1}{18} \sqrt[3]{n} \left(3 \log \left(n^{2/3}-\sqrt[3]{n}+1\right)-6 \log \left(\sqrt[3]{n}+1\right)+6 \sqrt{3} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 \sqrt[3]{n}-1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)+\pi  \sqrt{3}\right)$ which shows that the limit does not exist (it is $\infty$).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you think that your integral is $\int_0^1\frac{x}{x^3+1/n}$, in the limit it is the integral of $1/x^2$, so you should expect it to diverge.

Then you can do the following:
$$
\int_0^1\frac{nx}{nx^3+1}=\int_0^1\frac{x}{x^3+1/n}\geq\int_{1/n^{1/3}}^1\frac{x}{x^3+1/n}\geq\int_{1/n^{1/3}}^1\frac{x}{2x^3}\\ \ \\=\int_{1/n^{1/3}}^1\frac1{x^2}=n^{1/3}-1.
$$
So $$\lim_n\int_0^1\frac{nx}{nx^3+1}=\infty.$$

Comment: No $dx$? It's all wrong!

Comment: I'll put the $dx$ if it makes you happy... ;)

Comment: $\ddot \smile{{}}$

Comment: I think i got it, Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Not as good, as other answers, but still...

Since $\ 0<x<1$$$\int\limits_0^1\frac{nx}{nx^3+1}dx>\int\limits_0^1\frac{nx}{nx^2+1}dx=\ln\sqrt{n+1}\to\infty$$

Comment: Actually, this one is great.

Comment: I like this one better than mine.

Comment: Thanks. Others are just more obvious and give general idea of how to handle these types of problems, so they are more useful. Mine is not so obvious. But I can see why you like mine more - it's somewhat shorter and simplier ) Sorry for possible language mistakes, I'm Russian.

Answer (score 5):

Step 1: $$\frac{nx}{nx^3+1}=\frac{x}{x^3+\frac{1}{n}}$$
Step 2: $$\int_0^1 \frac{x}{x^3}dx~~\textrm{ diverges}$$

Comment: so here do we need to show uniform Convergence and then take limits inside?

Comment: So you first calculated the limit? Is it mathematically correct?

Comment: This isn't a complete solution, just a pair of hints.  See Martin's answer for a complete treatment.

Answer (score 1):

To add it in more explicit language:

You would like to exchange the limit and the integral, i.e. to write

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 f_n(x) dx
  = \int_0^1 \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) dx
  = \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x^2} = +\infty.$$

The [Lebesgue Monotone Convergence Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem) allows to do just that.

Comment: @MartinArgerami sorry, my bad. Will correct in a sed.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try to split this integral using partial fractions, treating $n$ as a constant :

$$\begin{eqnarray} I &=& \int_0^1 \frac{nx}{n x^3 + 1} dx \\
&=& \int_0^1 \frac A{n^{1/3} x + 1} dx + \int_0^1 \frac {B x + C}{n^{2/3} x^2 - n^{1/3}x + 1} dx \end{eqnarray}$$

Both integrals can be done using classical techniques. The rest is up to you.